# ADC strange behavior (ATmega)

Tags: avr, adc, atmega, uart, noise

I am building a hobby oscilloscope on ATmega16. I am testing ADC by generating a square wave at 2kHz with small amplitude and applying it to the ADC pin through a capacitive input with a voltage divider to shift zero-level.

[image: schematic]

This is how the signal looks after being sampled by ADC:
[image: schematic]

It looks fine, but after I start shifting zero-level by adjusting the potentiometer I get these strange spikes:
[image: schematic]

After shifting level a bit higher it looks fine again:
[image: schematic]

And then the pattern repeats:
[image: schematic]

[image: schematic]

[image: schematic]

Overall, I get 3 ranges where the spikes appear.

## Some info

- AVR is running at 16MHz
- ADC uses internal 2.56 reference voltage
- ADC is in free running mode at 125kHz (prescaler=128)
- I transfer data via CP210 to an android tablet which is used for real-time plotting. The circuit is also powered from the tablet. I get the same results when the circuit is connected to PC.
- USART baudrate is 500000b/s (UBRR=1)
- AVcc and AREF are not connected. I also tried connecting AVcc to Vcc and adding a .1uF cap between Gnd and AVcc but this had no effect.

## Some more info

- this noise does not come from the generator (tested with analog oscilloscope)
- this noise does not come from the potentiometer
- LFUSE = 0xFF, HFUSE = 0x89.

## ADC initialization routine

```
ADMUX = (1 << REFS0); // AVCC with external capacitor at AREF pin
ADCSRA = (1 << ADEN)
        | (1 << ADIE)
        | (1 << ADATE) 
        | (1 << ADPS0)
        | (1 << ADPS1)
        | (1 << ADPS2); // Division factor = 128
MCUCR |= 1 << SM0;
MCUCR |= 1 << SE; // Sleep-mode enabled
ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);
```

## ADC data transfer routine

```
volatile uint8_t adcLow;
volatile uint8_t adcHigh;

int main(void) {
    ....
    while (1) {
        if (ADCSRA != 0x00) {
            USARTSendByte(adcLow);
            USARTSendByte(adcHigh);
        }
    }
}

ISR(ADC_vect) {
    adcLow = ADCL;
    adcHigh = ADCH;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a different pot?

Comment: Yes, I have. The pot does not cause the problem.

Comment: Is it a single data point in your data or are there multiple datapoints that make up that spike. Or put differently: Is it just one single measurement causing the spike? Also: Does that also happen when you sample with a lower speed?

Comment: When using avr-gcc you can use the following shortcut: `uint16_t adcValue = ADC;`

Comment: I don't have a generator right now so I will have to test this tomorrow. Sampling at a lower speed is not possible because the prescaler is 128 (which is the highest possible value). However I did try using a slower usart baundrate but it didn't help.

Comment: @jippie thanks for the tip, but I was splitting ADC results intentionally, because I can only send one byte at a time over usart.

Comment: I think it is better to set your own flag in the ISR than depending on ADCSRA, I think you are experiencing a run condition with ADSC and ADIF. Or test one particular bit in the register.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spikes are clearly clipping to very particular values (probably a power of two) or you are using signed integers that are too small to contain the whole value.

You didn't supply full source code so I'm guessing here. You probably try to fit the measured value into a too small integer. Make a dump of the vaules you get and find the peaks in them. Then look at the binary representation of these numbers and see if you can find something in common.

With quick estimation the distance between two peaks is about 1.28V, a little bit too coincidentially close to the size of a signed 8 bit integer.

I advice to use type definitions like `int8_t` [-128:127], `uint8_t` [0:255], `int16_t` [-32768:32767], `uint16_t` [0:65535], `int32_t` [-2147483648:2147483647] and `uint32_t` [0:4294967295], which clearly shows how large the variable is.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question with source code. `adcLow` and `adcHigh` are of `uint8_t` type so the size is sufficient to hold ADC values.

Comment: Bitten by the type-casting bug then?

Comment: This might be the case. I am converting received values like this:                                          `int value = (buffer[i + 1] << 8 | (buffer[i] & 0xFF))` in Java.

Comment: You were correct that these spikes are software-related. I've just discovered that they occur due to transmission error. I asked another question [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/85826/usart-transmission-errors-with-cp210x)

Comment: Wait .. isn't uint8_t [0, 255], and int8_t [-128, 127] ? Wasn't the U making the type unsigned ?

Comment: @geoh whoops, let met correct that. Good catch.